# Memoir: Make content occupy whole width

Tags: margins, memoir

In memoir document class, I want the content to occupy the whole width: So the content should start where the black line of the heading starts and should end where the black line ends.

How can I do that?

[image: Content doesn't occupy whole width]

Currently, my content starts left or right of the black line, as you can see in the above image.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Hi and thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what you have done but I'm guessing that you used `memoir`'s `Ruled` pagestyle. `memoir` typesets the text according to the `\textwidth` but the `Ruled` pagestyle extends the page header into the margin. If this is what you have done then the text is the normal width but the header is wider.

What do you want?

If you want the text and header to be the same width then use the `ruled` pagestyle. If you want the text to be wider then change the page layout as described in the manual (`texdoc memoir`), but with the `Ruled` headstyle the header will still be wider than the text.

Comment: Okay thanks! Ended up using ruled and making margins wider ( \setlrmarginsandblock{3.7cm}{3.7cm}{*}  \checkandfixthelayout )

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not submit any MWE and therefore there is no enough information of which package(s) or settings did you actually use. I will assume this simple setting at which the `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` with the default style `\pagestyle{fancy}` will do you what you want (paragraph text width same as the header ruler width), as follows:

[image]

The simple minimum code is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext} % to generate dummy text
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[7]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note `fancyhdr` should generally not be used with `memoir` which has its own more tightly integrated headers/footers